# Sequentially run tests in different collections

Tags: c#, xunit

I have a bunch of integration tests that need to run sequentially because they interact with a database. The order in which the tests are executed does not matter, as long as at most one test is running at a given moment. According to the [documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel), this can be achieved by grouping the tests in a collection. However, not all my tests share the same fixture, so I need at least two collections:

```
[CollectionDefinition("Collection A")]
public class CollectionA : ICollectionFixture<CollectionAFixture>
{
}

[CollectionDefinition("Collection B")]
public class CollectionB: ICollectionFixture<CollectionBFixture>
{
}
```

With this setup, tests from Collection A are run at the same time as tests from Collection B, which results in race conditions.

**My question**: is there a way to specify that the tests in both collections should be run sequentially, as if they were all part of a single collection?

I am aware that it is possible to disable parallelism using the xUnit console runner. However, I would prefer solving this in the source code, so other developers don't need to tweak their configuration.

Comment: So a test can not run by itself? It is dependent on that some other test has run before it?

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to restore a fresh DB image before each test, so that individual tests do not influence each other. Tests that must be run in a certain order are not a good idea...

Comment: @Magnus the order in which tests are run does not matter. I just updated the question to clarify that ;)

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider you are right. Fortunately, our tests don't need to run in a certain order.

Comment: We handled this by introducing an `IntegrationTest` base class that drops and recreates the DB in `[TestInitialize]`, i.e. before each individual test. Every test that needs a DB inherits from  `IntegrationTest`. `[TestInitialize]` attribute is for MSTEST, not sure what the xunit syntax is.

Comment: Note that we already manage dropping and creating the DB. The remaining problem is concurrent access to the DB. To some extent my question is quite specific to xUnit.

Comment: Instead of dropping and re-creating, have each test run in a transaction that is rolled back. (done in the base class) that will solve your problem with concurrent execution since the transaction scope will handle that.

Comment: I think we are getting bogged down in implementation details. I mentioned a database as an example of a stateful resource we depend on in our tests, but there are other resources as well. In the end it really comes down to: can I make xUnit run all my tests sequentially without resorting to configuration files?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can of course always create a lock scope for your critical code.